# Why file_put_contents is not working?

Tags: php

I have used `file_put_contents` before. No problem was there. But this time I want to use it within the function but it doesn't create my desired file. Can you help me please?

```
function add_registered_user($name, $email) {

file_put_contents('mailing_list.php', "$name: $email\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have permission for creating/writing that file?

Comment: 'mailing_list.php' Really bad idea create php file through script..

Comment: `file_put_contents` is a function that returns a value. Did you at least check its result?

Comment: What permission? I'm a new user, so all things are not clear.   @DonCallisto

Comment: @SadiqAhmad: new user? What do you mean? For "permission" I mean Operationg System permission, you know, read, write, execute, and so on ...

Comment: error reporting is on. there is no error warning. @SyedQarib

Comment: should I create it on .txt file? @alexey palamar

Answer (score -1):

Set CHMOD 777 on the folder that will hold the file.
You can do it at your FTPclient, or if your local you just rightclick->propertise on the folder.

Comment: why never? Im used to write and read invoices through php. Simply put that php is the only thing that is permitted to acces folder..? @DonCallisto

Comment: So why do you need to set 777 if PHP is the only one that can write?

Comment: Hello Darloz, I'm working on Windows7. So how can I change permission. I'm trying but still not found a way.